# Postman post request works ok but exported Ruby Don

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, multipartform-data

Post request work in Postman but the same code exported in Ruby doesn't work. It is a request

```
Content-Type= application/x-www-form-urlencoded with body 
content-type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
```

I need to send a confirmation to payU for IDN. The request works ok if it is send from Postman but not working ok when I ran the same code from ruby. (their server's answer is "Invalid account code" which is equivalent with no parameters received by payU.)

Request makes a post requests to

```
https://sandbox.payu.ro/order/idn.php
```

with header:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
with 
    body: multipart/form-date and the parameters:
    MERCHANT=GOISTEST
    ORDER_REF=304911
    ORDER_AMOUNT=35.70
    ORDER_CURRENCY=RON
    IDN_DATE=2019-05-26 07:50:39
    ORDER_HASH=b27e42645e9c52b81fab955eb7309f70
```

```
The Postman request result is 
<EPAYMENT>304911|7|Order already confirmed|2019-05-26 08:57:52|5c25acc698cb607a2af3676fdbaabf7b</EPAYMENT>
```

If you export in Ruby and run it you get an error for Error EOF
but if you add:

```
http.use_ssl = true
```

then the request is done and response is:

> "Invalid account code"

I would need the request to work in ruby!

This is the code exported by postman to Ruby:

```
The Postman request result is
<EPAYMENT>304911|7|Order already confirmed|2019-05-26 08:57:52|5c25acc698cb607a2af3676fdbaabf7b</EPAYMENT>
```

If you export in Ruby and run it you get an error for Error EOF
but if you add:

```
http.use_ssl = true
```

then the request is done and response is:

> "Invalid account code"

This is the server's answer when you do not send the parameters at all!
"What more can I do? "

Comment: Who does your Ruby source code actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out from that 
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-Setting+Headers
that 
**request["content-type"] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----NEW_BOUNDARY'**
is not working but 
    **request.content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----NEW_BOUNDARY'**
works.
I could make finnaly the post after many hours of debugging.